# Immutable data in Redux - Spread vs Object.freeze vs ImmutableJs/Immer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js, immer.js

I'm trying to get my heading around why in Redux they recommend using ImmutableJS when editing the initialState. I've read the official docs but it's still a bit unclear. When editing state in a reducer, I've always just used the spread operator. Is the purpose of using a library like ImmutableJS or Immer for when you have nested data in Redux? I can do this with the spread operator, however i presume this can maybe get unmanageable with lots of nested data and that is the purpose of using a library? https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns

If I should use a library like one of the suggested, is it best practice to use it even if the state is online 1 level, or only when data is nested?

Answer (score 4):

[We specifically recommend ***against*** using Immutable.js](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-plain-javascript-objects-for-state), and [*do* recommend using Immer](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#use-immer-for-writing-immutable-updates) (preferably as part of [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org).

You're welcome to continue writing immutable updates by hand if you'd like, but Immer simplifies your immutable update logic considerably.

(Note that we're working on a major rewrite of the Redux core docs, and will be trying to update some of the material to be more consistent as part of that, such as removing the docs page that discusses use of Immmutable.js.)

Comment: Hey @markerikson thanks for the response. So I guess for simple logic spreading is fine, but for anything nested or more complex to use Immer to avoid potential re-renders/issues.

Comment: "Potential re-renders" isn't the concern. It's how complex the immutable logic can become (especially if you're dealing with nested objects), how hard it is to read that logic, and how easy it is to make mistakes while writing that logic.